# Configurable product, duplicating SKU in sales->orders

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have created few simple products (sizes) in admin panel. My task is to create configurable product programmatically. When I create configurable product programmatically I use those simple products (loading by their IDs). But when I go to the page of that configurable product and choose size (simple product) and place order, in admin panel (Sales -> Orders) this configurable product has the SKU of simple product. How to avoid to setup simple product SKU for configurable product? The reason why I need this is I can have many products with same SKU in sales -> orders.

Comment: I edited your question but still its not clear what you are asking! Please be more specific. For example you could provide a screenshot to make it clearer for us.

Answer (score -1):

public function getSku() {
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getItem()->getProductId());
return $product->getSku();
}